# Unable to retrieve WP post feature image url through JSON

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

was looking for a way to get the post featured image but it doesn't seem to output the data using {{ post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'].link }} although _embed was used. Was wondering if there is anything wrong with my code and that someone could guide me out?

```js
export class WordPressRestapiService {

  baseRestApiUrl: string = this.appConfig.Shop_URL + '/wp-json/wp/v2/';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, public appConfig: AppConfig) { }

  getRecentPosts(categoryId: number, page: number = 1): Observable<Post[]> {
    // Get posts by a category if a category id is passed
    let category_url = categoryId ? ("&categories=" + categoryId) : "";

    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseRestApiUrl + "posts?_embed&page=" + page + category_url ).pipe(
      map((posts: Post[]) => {
        return posts.map((post) => new Post(post));
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return Observable.throw('Something went wrong ;)');
      })
    );
  }

  getPost(postId: number): Observable<Post> {
   return this.httpClient.get(this.baseRestApiUrl + "posts/" + postId + "?_embed").pipe(
     map(post => {
       return new Post(post);
     }),
     catchError(error => {
       return Observable.throw('Something went wrong ;)');
     })
   );
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get post feature image , if your json called " post" , in .html file use

```
<img  src="{{post?._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0]?.media_details.sizes.full.source_url}}">
```

Comment: Thanks but it turned out all data couldn't be parsed after that.

Comment: what do you mean ? in my code , "post" is the name of json data and it's an example , put it in the img tag in .html

Comment: It seems the post without featured image would return ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined